# custom interval filter in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

I have a collection which is ordered well until i use my custom filter on it. The filter does check if a value of each key in the collection is in a certain range.

Case 1: works fine.

```
ng-repeat="match in matches | orderBy: matchnumber"
```

Case 2: does not order! range check performs well.

```
ng-repeat="match in matches | orderBy: matchnumber | range:1:20"

ng-repeat="match in matches | range:1:20 | orderBy: matchnumber"
```

My filter:

```
myApp.filter('range', function() {
    return function(matches, min, max) {
        var result = {};

        angular.forEach(matches, function(match, key) {
            if (match.matchnumber >= min && match.matchnumber <= max) {
                 result[key] = match;
            }
        });

        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you make result an array, and result.push(match) instead?

Comment: yes, that made it. didn't notice i was using an object declaration. thanks